# Fetch geometry based on fields

Tags: c++, gdal

if I have a datasource with only polygons, and each polygon has a field of
string, let's say its name, this name is unique for each geometry, they are
attributed dynamically
The more the name of a geometry is similar with another, the more the
geometries are close.

What I want to do is to fetch all the geometries for which the name begins
with something given by the user.

I looked GDAL's algorithms but it seems that nothing fits my problem, maybe
I didn't search enough, and I don't want to look at all the geometries to
find ones that fit.

Thanks,

**EDIT :**

As mentioned in the commentaries I didn't give any example of what I'm trying to do.

So, I'm using GDAL and OGR libraries (v1.11.0) in C++ because I have to work with raster and vector datas at the same time.
In my process I use the function GDALPolygonize() to extract the polygon, here an sample :

```
GDALDataset dataset; //this a dataset of int32
size_t width, height;
//Do something with the dataset
const char *pszDriverName = "ESRI Shapefile";
OGRSFDriver *poDriver;

OGRRegisterAll();

poDriver = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::GetRegistrar()->GetDriverByName(
                                 pszDriverName );
if( poDriver == NULL )
  {
printf( "%s driver not available.\n", pszDriverName );
exit( 1 );
  }
OGRDataSource *poDS;

poDS = poDriver->CreateDataSource("name.shp", NULL );
if( poDS == NULL )
  {
printf( "Creation of output file failed.\n" );
exit( 1 );
  }

OGRLayer *poLayer;

poLayer = poDS->CreateLayer( "region", NULL, wkbPolygon, NULL );
if( poLayer == NULL )
  {
printf( "Layer creation failed.\n" );
exit( 1 );
  }

OGRFieldDefn oField( "id", OFTString ); //I use string but there i can use another type

oField.SetWidth(32);

if( poLayer->CreateField( &oField ) != OGRERR_NONE )
  {
printf( "Creating Name field failed.\n" );
exit( 1 );
  }

GDALPolygonize(dataset->GetRasterBand(1), nullptr, poLayer, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);


OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource( poDS );
GDALClose(dataset);
```

This code is mostly taken from the GDAL website.

So, I use  the polygons given by OGRPolygon. Then, later, the user selected a polygon and the goal is to find those who share a certain number of bits.

Thanks to GDAL I can use, the OGRFeature and OGRField, but my only idea is to list each polygons, but i'm sure there is better way to accomplish this task

Hopefully it clearer.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because you didn't provide any code to explain what you mean about the definition of your `polygon` type.

Comment: OK tkanks I'll try to be more explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient way is to implement this as a lookup in a [radix tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).

Comment: Thank you, I think I can use such a data structure, it seems to fit my problem

Comment: @user3497357 no need to thank. The accept and vote feature is for that.